# Database Model Design [EntityFramework]

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to design some DB Models for an Order system. Essentially, I plan on having different types of orders - for example, a screw part order, a bolt part order, etc. Each order type has a different property that needs to be stored. My issue is with maintaining a unique order ID across all the types. For example, if somebody orders a screw, it should have a order ID of 1. And then if somebody orders a bolt, it should have an order ID of 2. My proposed design is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OrderSystem.Models
{
    public class ScrewOrder
    {
        [Key]
        public int orderID { get; set; }

        public int partSerial { get; set; }
        public String ScrewType { get; set; }
        public float width { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OrderSystem.Models
{
    public class BoltOrder
    {
        [Key]
        public int orderID { get; set; }

        public int partSerial { get; set; }
        public String BoltType { get; set; }
        public float length { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The issue is as follows - **How can I keep the OrderID to be unique to be both ScrewOrder and BoltOrder?**

Would it better to have a general "Order" class? If so, how would the implementation happen in that case?

Keep in mind that I am new to EntityFramework and ORBs in general.

Comment: Sounds like you want an Order class, and have ScrewOrder and BoltOrder inherit from that. Entity Framework does allow inheritance, this tutorial should help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Ah yes! That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!